# Replacing abnormally large values with nan in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, replace, nan

I have the following column from a data file which I am trying to plot.

```
[   2.21    2.34    2.56    2.78  180.      3.32    4.57    2.89  286.
    2.46    3.76    4.89   10.13]
```

So, in my datasets sometimes I have this drastically sharp increase in values like (2.78 180 3.32) & (2.89 286 2.46). I want to replace this abnormal values with np.nan. I am trying to input a condition like this [if x(i)>5(x(i-1)+x(i+1)), then x(i)=np.nan] which means whenever a i-th value of x (x being the column values) is so much greater than its previous and next values, python will replace the value with np.nan, so that it doesn't get plotted or considered. 
But I haven't been able to put that in coding format. Any help would be so much helpful.

```
import numpy as np
data=np.loadtxt('/Users/Hrihaan/Desktop/Data.txt')
x=data[:,1]
print(x)
```

Comment: What are the boundary conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition `x(i)>5(x(i-1)+x(i+1))` can be tested for `i = 1,...,n-1`, where `n` is the largest allowable index of `x`. 
A vectorized version which tests this condition for all `i`s would be:

```
mask = (x[1:-1] > 5*(x[2:]+x[:-2]))
```

And you could then assign `np.nan` to those locations where the `mask` is True by using:

```
x[1:-1][mask] = np.nan
```

Note that `x[1:-1]` is a [slice of `x`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) -- and that is important because slices (as opposed to arrays obtained through so-called ["advanced indexing"](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing)) are views of the original array, `x`. So modifying the view, `x[1:-1]`, affects the original array `x`. Thus, assigning to `x[1:-1][mask]` affects not only the slice `x[1:-1]` but `x` itself.

Indexing with a boolean mask invokes advanced indexing which returns a new array (not a view). So in contrast, the assignment `x[mask][1:-1] = np.nan` would not work because modifying `x[mask]` would not affect `x` itself. (It also would not work for a more mundane reason -- `mask` is the wrong length.)

---

Let's give it a try:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([ 2.21, 2.34, 2.56, 2.78, 180., 3.32, 4.57, 2.89, 286., 2.46, 3.76, 4.89, 10.13])
mask = (x[1:-1] > 5*(x[2:]+x[:-2]))
# array([False, False, False,  True, False, False, False,  True, False,
#        False, False], dtype=bool)
x[1:-1][mask] = np.nan

print(x)
# array([  2.21,   2.34,   2.56,   2.78,    nan,   3.32,   4.57,   2.89,
#         nan,   2.46,   3.76,   4.89,  10.13])
```

---

To better understand `(x[1:-1] > 5*(x[2:]+x[:-2]))` it helps to look at a simplified example:

```
In [57]: x = np.arange(8); x
Out[57]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

`x[2:]` slices off the first two items from `x`:

```
In [58]: x[2:]
Out[58]: array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

`x[:-2]` slices off the last two items from `x`:

```
In [59]: x[:-2]
Out[59]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

`x[1:-1]` slices of the first and last items from `x`:

```
In [60]: x[1:-1]
Out[60]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

NumPy arithmetic is performed *element-wise*. So  `(x[2:]+x[:-2])` computes `x(i-1)+x(i+1)` for `i=1,...,n-1`:

```
In [61]: (x[2:]+x[:-2])
Out[61]: array([ 2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12])
```

So we have this situation:

```
|   i | x(i-1) | x(i+1) | x(i)   |
|-----+--------+--------+--------|
|   1 | x(0)   | x(2)   | x(1)   |
|   2 | x(1)   | x(3)   | x(2)   |
|   3 | x(2)   | x(4)   | x(3)   |
| ... |        |        |        |
| n-1 | x(n-1) | x(n)   | x(n-1) |
|-----+--------+--------+--------|
        ^        ^        ^
        |        |        |
        |        |        o--- This column is the array x[1:-1]
        |        |
        |        o------------ This column is the array x[2:]
        |
        o--------------------- This column is the array x[:-2]
```

---

Another way to look it is: once you know the condition is for `i=1,...,n-1`, then `x(i)` obviously becomes `x[1:-1]` since it starts at index 1 and ends 1 index before the last possible index.
Next, `x(i-1)` and `x(i+1)` can be thought of as the elements to the left and right of `x(i)`. So we are dealing with `x[1:-1]` shifted by one index to the left and one index to the right.
So shifting `x[1:-1]` by one index to the right produces `x[2:]` and shifting `x[1:-1]` by one index to the left produces `x[:-2]`.

---

By the way, one of the [beautiful
properties](https://plus.google.com/115212051037621986145/posts/YTUxbXYZyfi) of
Python's half-open slice syntax is that `x[a:b]` has `(b-a)` elements.  So
`x[1:-1]` (which is equivalent to `x[1:n-1]`) has `n-2` elements. Noting that
there are 2 missing elements makes it easy to guess that arrays adjacent to
`x[1:-1]` are `x[2:]` and `x[:-2]`.

Comment: @Hrihaan: I added a bit above to hopefully explain the source of those indices.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so I was wondering if I only want to apply the condition to the next value or previous value, like x(i)>5(x(i+1)) or x(i)>5(x(i-1)), I tried to use mask = (x[1:-1] > 5*(x[2:]) and then x[1:-1][mask] = np.nan, but its giving me  invalid syntax error.

Comment: @Hrihaan: `mask = (x[1:-1] > 5*(x[2:])` needs a closing parenthesis at the end. (Tip: It helps to use a text editor which has [brace matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brace_matching) and some key combination which allows you to jump the cursor across closed parentheses and braces.)

Comment: So, I tried it for this array [ 12.   2.   3.   1.  22.   4.   5.   8.  10.  11.], where the first value 12 > 5* (the next value which is 2), also the fifth value 22 > 5*(the next value which is 4), so 12 and 22 should have been replaced by nan, I used mask = (x[1:-1] > 2*(x[2:])) and then
x[1:-1][mask1] = np.nan, but it didn't work, 12 and 22 were not replaced.

Answer (score 2):

If occurrences of abnormal values are rare (abnormal == rare kind of by definition), then using integer indexing instead of the boolean indexing used in @unutbu's answer would be significantly more efficient, especially in large arrays:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([ 2.21, 2.34, 2.56, 2.78, 180., 3.32, 4.57, 2.89, 286., 2.46, 3.76, 4.89, 10.13])
xp = np.pad(x, 1, 'reflect') # to deal with boundaries
idx = np.where(x > 5*(xp[2:]+xp[:-2]))
x[idx] = np.nan
```